# Converting SQL type to PLSQL collection / converting one collection type to another

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections, sql-types

Trying to convert SQL type collection to PLSQL type.

```
-- create an SQL type
create or replace type arrayforvarchar as table of varchar2(30);
/
```

Check below anonymous block:

```
declare
    type arrayforvarcharplsql is table of varchar2(30);
    var_plsql_array arrayforvarcharplsql;
    var_sql_array arrayforvarchar := arrayforvarchar();
begin
    select cola
    bulk collect into var_plsql_array
    FROM (
        select 'X' as cola from dual
        union all
        select 'Y' as cola from dual
        );
end;
/
```

How is it possible to assign values of `var_plsql_array` to `var_sql_array` apart from using loops?

Anyway simple assignment isn't working.

Answer (score 4):

Not that I can find:

Using a simple assignment doesn't work as the arrays have different types:

```sql
declare
    type arrayforvarcharplsql is table of varchar2(30);
    var_plsql_array arrayforvarcharplsql;
    var_sql_array arrayforvarchar;
begin
    var_plsql_array := arrayforvarcharplsql( 'X', 'Y' );
    
    var_sql_array := var_plsql_array;
end;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ORA-06550: line 8, column 22:
> PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
> ORA-06550: line 8, column 5:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> ```

Trying to use `CAST` doesn't work in a PL/SQL scope as it only works in an SQL scope:

```sql
declare
    type arrayforvarcharplsql is table of varchar2(30);
    var_plsql_array arrayforvarcharplsql;
    var_sql_array arrayforvarchar;
begin
    var_plsql_array := arrayforvarcharplsql( 'X', 'Y' );
    
    var_sql_array := CAST( var_plsql_array AS arrayforvarchar );
end;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ORA-06550: line 8, column 22:
> PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column '' may be used inside a SQL statement only
> ORA-06550: line 8, column 5:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> ```

Trying to pass the PL/SQL collection into an SQL scope to be able to use `CAST` doesn't work as PL/SQL collections can't be used in the SQL scope:

```sql
declare
    type arrayforvarcharplsql is table of varchar2(30);
    var_plsql_array arrayforvarcharplsql;
    var_sql_array arrayforvarchar;
begin
    var_plsql_array := arrayforvarcharplsql( 'X', 'Y' );
    
    SELECT CAST( var_plsql_array AS arrayforvarchar )
    INTO   var_sql_array
    FROM   DUAL;
end;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ORA-06550: line 8, column 18:
> PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements
> ```

Trying to pass the PL/SQL collection into a table collection expression in the SQL scope and using `BULK COLLECT` doesn't work for the same reason as the previous:

```sql
declare
    type arrayforvarcharplsql is table of varchar2(30);
    var_plsql_array arrayforvarcharplsql;
    var_sql_array arrayforvarchar;
begin
    var_plsql_array := arrayforvarcharplsql( 'X', 'Y' );
    
    SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
    BULK COLLECT INTO var_sql_array
    FROM   TABLE( var_plsql_array );
end;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ORA-06550: line 10, column 19:
> PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements
> ORA-06550: line 10, column 12:
> PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
> ORA-06550: line 8, column 5:
> PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
> ```

However, using loops and assigning values individually does work:

```sql
declare
    type arrayforvarcharplsql is table of varchar2(30);
    var_plsql_array arrayforvarcharplsql;
    var_sql_array arrayforvarchar;
begin
    var_plsql_array := arrayforvarcharplsql( 'X', 'Y' );
    
    var_sql_array := arrayforvarchar();
    var_sql_array.EXTEND( var_plsql_array.COUNT );
    FOR i IN 1 .. var_plsql_array.COUNT LOOP
      var_sql_array(i) := var_plsql_array(i);
    END LOOP;
end;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=74b0ea35bea91f036d49ad1c35a451ad)*

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot assign the values of one collection type to another collection type without using the loops. See [Assigning Values to Collection Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-7836EEC3-2642-4CF8-AA50-81034855119D):

> **Data Type Compatibility**
> You can assign a collection to a collection variable only if they have the same data type.
> Having the same element type is not enough.

Even if either of these collections are declared in PL/SQL, it will not work:

```
declare 
    type t1 is table of int;
    type t2 is table of int;
    a t1 := t1 (1);
    b t2;
begin b := a;
end;
/
ORA-06550: line 6, column 12:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

There is no internal function like `CAST` to convert a collection of one type to a collection of another type. Although you can use your own function to *hide* the loop. Reproducible example:

```
create or replace type arrsql as table of varchar2 (30);
/
var rc refcursor
declare
    type arrpls is table of varchar2(30);
    source arrpls := arrpls ('aaa','bbb','ccc');
    target arrsql;
    function cast (s arrpls, astypeof arrsql) return arrsql is
        t arrsql := arrsql ();
    begin
        t.extend (s.count); 
        for i in 1..s.count loop t(i) := s(i); end loop;
        return t;
    end; 
begin
    target := cast (source, astypeof=>target);
    open :rc for select * from table (target);
end;
/

Result Sequence
------------------------------
aaa
bbb
ccc
```